# pthreads passing argument 3 warning

Tags: c, linked-list, pthreads

At the moment I'm getting a argument 3 error when I try to use my thread to execute the decFunk process. I've seen examples and they mention that I need to have a void parameter but I'm not really sure how to do that.

```
void *decFunk(PQueue* pQ){
    pQ->currentProcess = pQ->firstProcess;
    int temp = pQ->currentProcess->duration;
    pQ->firstProcess->duration = temp -1;

    if(pQ->currentProcess->duration == 0){
        pQ->firstProcess = pQ->firstProcess->next;
    }   
    return NULL;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);

    sem_init(&tLock,0,0);
    sem_init(&qLock,0,0);

    FILE * fIn;
    PQueue* sortQ;
    sortQ = startQueue();   

    printf("Enter number of threads you want to use.");
    pthread_t threads;

    pthread_create(&threads ,NULL , decFunk, sortQ);


    for(t = 0; t< 5; t++){
        fIn = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        printf("Time: %d\n", t);
        readIn(fIn, sortQ);
        printQ(sortQ);

        t++;
        fclose(fIn);
        sleep(1);
    }
pthread_join(&threads,NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: The prototype for `pthread_create()` is `int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);`, so yes, the last parameter of `pthread_create()` and the only parameter of the function you pass *is* a `void*`, regardless of whether you "are sure about that".

Comment: I was more or less asking how does one make a void parameter, I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: As long as the prototype for `pthread_create()` is visible when you call it, the conversion from `PQueue*` to `void*` is implicit when you pass `sortQ` to `pthread_create()`. You'll just have to change `decFunk()` to `void *decFunk(void* pQ)`.

Comment: Could you show your compile flags and error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Pointer conversions to/from a `void *` are covered by this section of the specification:

> §**6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>   A pointer to any object type may be converted to
>   a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to
>   the original pointer.

The conversion is automatic if you pass a non-void pointer to a function that takes a `void *` as a parameter. The conversion is also automatic if you assign a `void *` to a non-void pointer, or vice versa.

So the relevant bits of the code can be written as:

```
#include <pthread.h>    // tells the compiler that pthread_create takes a void* argument

void *decFunk(void *arg){
    PQueue* pQ = arg;   // implicit cast from void* back to the original pointer

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    PQueue* sortQ;
    sortQ = startQueue();   

    pthread_create(&threads, NULL, decFunk, sortQ); // sortQ implicitly cast to void*

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The arguments are only converted to `void*` if the expression denotes the called function has a type that includes a prototype.

Comment: @EOF What do you mean by *"the called function has a type that includes a prototype."*

Comment: If you just declared `int pthread_create()`, rather than `int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)`, the arguments would *not* be automatically converted.

Comment: @EOF Yes, agreed, that's why it's important to `#include <pthread.h>` so that you have the full prototype.